# how to manipulate dom in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i have below jquery code, how to write it in the angular way. I want to change the name of carradvSearch.

```
$('.CarrAdvSearch').click(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass("CarrAdvSearch")){
             $('#advSrchPannel').show()
            $('#CarrAdvSearch').text("Basic Search")                
            $('.CarrAdvSearch').addClass("carrBscSearch")
            $('.CarrAdvSearch').removeClass("CarrAdvSearch");
    }else{
          $('#CarrAdvSearch').text("Advance Search")
            $('.carrBscSearch').addClass("CarrAdvSearch");
            $('.carrBscSearch').removeClass("carrBscSearch");               
            $('#advSrchPannel').hide()
    }
```

})

Comment: angular way its a angular way dude, read the HOLY ANGULAR DOCUMENTAION, and look at simple example at the home page! https://angularjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to do some learning first. Most of the stuff you need is covered in the official tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

To answer your question in short: you need to use angular directives:

`ng-click` to assign a click handler for a dom element;

`ng-class` to add/remove css classes based on some conditions;

`ng-show` / `ng-hide` to show / hide dom elements.